# I have a problem with this AES-CTR syntax. Can anyone help me solve it?

Tags: python, aes

```
class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = get_random_bytes(16)
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CTR)
        self.nonce = self.cipher.nonce
        
    def encrypt(self, data):
        cipher_text = self.cipher.encrypt(data.encode())
        return base64.b64encode(cipher_text)

    def decrypt(self, cipher_text):
        decrypt_cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=self.nonce)
        plain_text = decrypt_cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(cipher_text))
        return plain_text
```

The problem is when I encrypt and decrypt and have another encrypt and decrypt the output is not the same plaintext.

Comment: The `Cipher` object is stateful, see [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#modern-modes-of-operation-for-symmetric-block-ciphers). Your problem is probably caused by this. Post the caller code for a repro.

Comment: Your implementation has several vulnerabilities/drawbacks. You can find sample implementations in the PyCryptodome documentation, e.g. [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode) for CTR.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with the syntax?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question